# Gradle error when compiling flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle

I'm trying to run my flutter app, but it gives the following gradle error, can someone help me? I tried some of the stack's own solutions but n solved it.

My code build.grade is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This error is: 
[Message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82XpY.png)

**UPDATE**

I have solved above error but now get error like this,

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using 
BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using 
BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug 
 option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 6s
 Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: You can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/60707284/11427294

Comment: I managed to solve that error by changing or flutter sdk, but I have another error now

Answer (score 0):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```