# How to configure Azure AD SSO login for Mode : SINGLE? in Gradle

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on

Can someone help me how to configure the Gradle dependency and steps for Azure AD SSO login?

Answer (score 0):

***To configure Azure AD SSO login for Gradle, please try the following:***

*Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications -> Gradle Enterprise -> Manage section -> select single sign-on -> Select the method.*

To make sure the steps to configure Azure AD SSO login for in Gradle, please refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/gradle-enterprise-tutorial).

The error ***"Could not read script 'E:\Santhosh\Practice\AzureLoginSSO\gradle\versions.gradle' as it does not exist."*** usually occurs if the file is not sync'd properly.

- Make sure to **sync** the Gradle file with your Project.
- Make sure the path of Gradle file is valid.
- Manually try updating the **`build.gradle`** file for all projects.
- Check whether there is any firewall blocking the access.

**Please refer the below links which might give you a pointer to resolve the issue:**

[vue.js - capacitor.settings.gradle' as it does not exist by Dmitry R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267827/capacitor-settings-gradle-as-it-does-not-exist)

[Problem occurred configuring root project building the gradle by Hussein Al-Mosawi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60704868/a-problem-occurred-configuring-root-project-android-when-building-the-gradle-b)

[Could not read script '.../versions.gradle' as it does not exist GitHub](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/259)